# AppBar layout scroll with coordinator layout hiding some view in bottom in Android pre lollipop version?

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I am using tab layout in the bottom with coordinator layout and appbar layout but it is showing some white space in bottom in pre lollipop version but working fine in above lollipop version.

**Xml Code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/light_grey_color"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="">

            <include layout="@layout/calendar_widget" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/light_grey_color">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_selected_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey_color"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/red_color" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_32dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <include layout="@layout/circular_chart" />

                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_stress_progress_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_32dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_stress"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
                        android:src="@mipmap/icon_stress" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_stress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_stress"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                        android:text="@string/text_stress"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_stress_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_gap"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_stress"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="(0 Minutes)"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16dp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_stress"
                        style="@style/StressProgressFill"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_stress"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_stress" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_work_progress_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_work"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
                        android:src="@mipmap/icon_work_out" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_work_out"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_work"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                        android:text="@string/text_work_out"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_work_out_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_gap"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_work_out"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                        android:text="(0 Minutes)"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16dp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_work_out"
                        style="@style/WorkoutProgress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_work_out"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_work" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_sleep_progress_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_sleep"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
                        android:src="@mipmap/icon_sleep" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_sleep"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_sleep"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                        android:text="@string/text_sleep"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_sleep_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_gap"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_sleep"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                        android:text="(0 Minutes)"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16dp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_sleep"
                        style="@style/SleepProgress"
                        android:layout_width="270dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_sleep"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_sleep" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Above lollipop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk2Ba.png)

[Pre lollipop version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEPoR.png)